# Filter Firestore data to only included the current users information

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to limit the data being returned from Firestore to the current user only.  Currently, my app is returning all users information to a listveiw on my home-screen which is not the intended outcome.  I have read a number of articles which describe how to achieve this but cant seem to get this going with my code (below).  I have Firestore DB with a single top-level Collection that holds a document for each Firebase auth'd user.  I don't want all documents/users information returned, only the current users document/user information.  Hopefully, I have provided the correct code where this change should be applied...

--- Database Services Code ------

```
 import 'package:example_app/models/family.dart'; import
 'package:example_app/models/user.dart'; import
 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 
 class DatabaseService {   final String uid;   DatabaseService({
 this.uid  });
 
   // collection reference   final CollectionReference familyCollection
 =  Firestore.instance.collection('family');   Future<void> updateUserData(
       String nameFirst,
       String nameLast,
      String phoneNumber,
      String profilePicture,
      String familyMemberID,
      String userID,
    ) async {  // String sugars, int strength) async {

      return await familyCollection.document(uid).setData({
        'nameFirst': nameFirst,
        'nameLast': nameLast,
        'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'profilePicture': profilePicture,
        'familyMemberID': familyMemberID,
        'userID': userID,
      });   }
  
    // family list from snapshot   List<Family>
  _familyListFormSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
        //print(doc.data);
        return Family(
            nameFirst: doc.data['nameFirst'] ?? '',
            nameLast: doc.data['nameLast'] ?? '',
            phoneNumber: doc.data['phoneNumber'] ?? '',
            profilePicture: doc.data['profilePicture'] ?? '',
            familyMemberID: doc.data['familyMemberID'] ?? '',
            userID: doc.data['userID'] ?? ''
        );
      }).toList();   }
  
    // user data from snapshots   UserData
  _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      return UserData(
          uid: uid,
          nameFirst: snapshot.data['nameFirst'],
          nameLast: snapshot.data['nameLast'],
          phoneNumber: snapshot.data['phoneNumber'],
          profilePicture: snapshot.data['profilePicture'],
          familyMemberID: snapshot.data['familyMemberID'],
          userID: snapshot.data['userID'],
      );   }
  
    // get profiles stream   Stream<List<Family>> get profiles {
      return familyCollection.snapshots()
          .map(_familyListFormSnapshot);   }
  
    // get user doc stream   Stream<UserData> get userData {
      return familyCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
          .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);   } }
```

Comment: Please don't come up with your own formatting for code, as it was pretty much unreadable the way you posted it. I quickly edit it to clean it up, but please click the edit link yourself too and fix any lingering problems, such as extra/missing line wraps, and the comment on line 7.

Answer (score 0):

To get current user information, you can specific the `document path` with `userUID` which I assume is the `documentId` of every user. That's it here's the query :

```
final data = await Firestore.instance
          .document("users/${currentUser.uid}")
          .get();
```

It return `DocumentSnapshot` so use the data like this : `data.data`

Comment: Thanks Aldy, I can see the logic but I just cant get it to work with my code.  No matter where I put it, it wont be accepted.  Any suggetstions on where in my code this will go?

Thanks once again,
Vincent.

Comment: Sure I'll help furthermore can you please provide more code where you try to get user document Thanks